# SAS EG Editor Macro to perform an operation on each line in the selection

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am using the Editor Macros feature that is part of the SAS Enterprise Guide software. I have written a small macro to reformat a line by removing the comma at the end, and moving it to the front (with two indentations before it). I would like to improve this by performing this reformat to *all* lines in the selection. I was hoping to replicate the method that 'Ctrl' + '/' uses, but I could not find any documentation for it.

The current snippet that works for a single line is below.

```
Move caret to end of line
Delete previous character
Move caret to beginning of line
Indent selection
Indent selection
Insert character ('.')
```

All I want to do is repeat the method above for each line in the current selection, but I do not know how to achieve this. When this is run with multiple lines selected, the operation is only performed on the final line.

For example, consider the following code block.

```
proc sql;
create table EXAMPLE2 as select
variable1,
variable2,
variable3,
variable4
from EXAMPLE;
quit;
```

The editor macro above when applied to the first three variable lines would produce the following code block.

```
proc sql;
create table EXAMPLE2 as select
    ,variable1
    ,variable2
    ,variable3
variable4
from EXAMPLE;
quit;
```

Currently, I would have to run the editor macro for each of the lines. I would rather be able to select the three lines, and run an editor macro that would call the macro above for each of the lines in the selection.

Also note that I would not leave the above code block as it is -- I would reformat it further by hand.

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more detail. Is this to data in a data set? If so, what does your actual code look like? Are you using a data step, which would automatically run this for each line?

Comment: @Reeza This is not to data in a data set, I'm using the editor macros to reformat the actual code itself. I will add a larger example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the editors regular expression replacement mode instead?

The enhanced editor is a COM object.  The COM object has macro capabilities surfaced in the EG ui.  EG does not provide additional programmatic interface or control over the enhanced editor.  A custom task can be written in .NET and registered as an add-in, the task would have more control over the the editor or editor instance.  See https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/How-do-I-add-a-SAS-editor-control-to-my-Custom-Task-for-code/td-p/1895.

The article states:

> You can simply use the SAS.Tasks.Toolkit.Controls.SASTextEditorCtl class.

and has links to many additional resources.